# Getting the list of modified fields in kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, web, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where editing is enabled.
I'm trying to:

1. catch the event that is executed when a field is modified within the
   grid.
2. Get the list of fields (or cells) modified within the grid row.

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide your code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found what I needed.
The event I was looking for is [save](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-save)

It is fired after the item is edited, when the item is being saved. This is where I need to plug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

This should get you where you need to go.

Comment: This helps if you read the documentation it tells you how to catch the event. You have to read through it.

Comment: Then better sending directly the link to  the document, don't think so?

Comment: I have posted the link to the save event, thanks @OnaBai for your comment